# Why isnt the website loading with WebView?

Tags: java, android

I have this code:

```
package com.example.webview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

and it works fine. But thats not exactly what I want to do. I want to open other urls like "https://www.instagram.com", but when I use this url the instagram loading screen apears and doesnt go away. I also tried it with other websites. The loading screen apears and doesnt go away. Why does it work only with "https://www.google.com"? How can I solve this problem?
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add two line :

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```